# Counting lines starting with a certain word

Tags: linux, count

How to count the number of lines in a text file starting with a certain word?

I do not want to use `sed` and then `wc -l`. Any better solution?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:-

```
  awk '/^yourwordtofind/{a++}END{print a}' file
```

Comment: There is another option as well if you want:- read -p 'Your word >>> ' pattern
awk -v pattern="$pattern" '$0 ~ pattern{c++}END{print c}' file

Comment: How to pass a shell variable to the command? I mean in cases that I need to count lines containing numbers...the following script did not work

Comment: for i in {0..16};
do
        for j in {0..16};
 do
        echo A $i B $j
        grep '^  A : "$i"  B : "$j"' file | wc -l
done
done

Comment: @user2517676:- Could you post another question for this as it will attract other members of SO too and you will get a  reply faster!!!

Answer (score 19):

Just grep your word and then use wc -l to count the lines... like this
`grep '^your_word' /path/to/file | wc -l`

Comment: if it must _begin_ with the word. then

    `grep '^word' /path/to/file/ | wc -l`

Comment: @thedarkwinter You're right forgot about the begin part. Thanks

Comment: How to pass a shell variable to the command? I mean in cases that I need to count lines containing numbers...the following script did not work

Comment: for i in {0..16}; do for j in {0..16}; do echo A $i B $j grep '^ A : "$i" B : "$j"' file | wc -l done done

Answer (score 6):

```
grep -c "pattern" <filename>
```

For example: If you want to search for a pattern `more` in a file `test.txt`, then below is the command:

```
grep -c "more" test.txt
```

Comment: ...and to anchor the pattern at the beginning of the line, you can use `^more`.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat <filename> | grep <word> | wc -l
```