# Count only lines with given character in front (<)

Tags: bash, csv, unix

I want to count the amount of lines in a CSV file. 
But only those with "<" at the beginning.

Comment: Almost identical: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40395018/counting-lines-starting-with-a-symbol), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28899349/find-lines-starting-with-one-specific-character-and-ending-with-another-one), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18489846/counting-lines-starting-with-a-certain-word)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `grep` with `c`:

```
grep -c '^<' <FILE>
```

Comment: up for most straightforward and simplest

Answer (score 2):

Use the awk, Luke:

```
$ cat file
foo
< this foo
not this foo <
< another of those foos
$ awk '/^</{c++}END{print c}' file
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the line containing '<' at the begining with `grep '^<'` and count remaining line with `wc -l`.

```
grep "^<" file.csv | wc -l
```

Answer (score -1):

```
grep -E "^<" filename | wc -l
```

Use regular expressions with grep to check for < at the start of the line (^) and then pipe through wc -l to get number of lines.